# Why do I have two instances of the same processes?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, memory, process

So I am playing around with one of my projects and what is causing an issue right now is when I click my `Start` button this method runs.

```
public void Start()
        {
            if (!ServerIsRunning)
            {
                ConsoleOutput.Clear();

                pServer = new Process();
                pServer.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
                pServer.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar " + "-Xms512M -Xmx1G myJavaFile.jar";

                pServer.Start();
                PID = pServer.Id;

                counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", pServer.ProcessName, true);

                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
```

I have created a global null property for the `PerformanceCounter` like so

```
private PerformanceCounter counter;
```

And as you can see in the start method that's where we are assigning it a value.

I created this tick event aswell for my timer that updates a property

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FindServerProcess();
            double pct = counter.NextValue() / 10;
            ServerCPU = pct.ToString("0.0");
        }
```

And here is the method inside that finds the process corresponding to a certain PID

```
public void FindServerProcess()
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.Id == PID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found the process!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click start it let's me know in the Output window that it finds the process as expected by printing out the message `Found the process!`.

However.. This is where it gets weird.
If I click my stop button

```
private void Stop(string StopCommand) 
{
     counter.Close();
     counter = null;
     timer.Stop();
     pServer.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(StopCommand);
}
```

it closes the counter, makes it null and I stop the timer that calls the tick event. Then I am also issuing a command which is just `stop` to the console stream which simply closes the process.
At this point the process has been closed, I cant see it in the Task manager anymore.
When I click start however, it starts prining out `Found the process!` two times at the time so parallel, and the property value it's changing seems to be double. Why is that? Am I not closing the property safely? Or did I forget to dispose of some objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem with two lines of `Found the process!` is caused by your `Start()` function, specifically the line:

```
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

As you described your actions of pressing, Start, Stop, and then Start again. The `timer.Tick` event is being added twice (once each time the `Start()` function is run.

To counter it, simply add the line

```
timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
```

beforehand.

Whenever you add an Event Handler at run time, you should always precede the call with the `-=` syntax to remove the previously assigned Event Handler (unless you really want it to run more than once)

Comment: Oh my.. Such a simple issue.. Good catch! Appriciate it!